# Different @INC at CGI script and shell

Tags: apache, perl, docker, environment-variables, cgi

I have following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
    test:
        image: httpd
        container_name: inc_test
        ports:
            - "3000:80"
        environment:
            - PERL5LIB=/somedir
            - PERLLIB=/somedir
        command:
            - bash
            - -c
            - |
                cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf | grep modules/mod_cgid.so
                sed -i 's,#\(LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so\),\1,g' /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
                cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf | grep modules/mod_cgid.so
                echo '#!/usr/bin/env perl' >> /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
                echo 'print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";' >> /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
                echo 'print join("\n", @INC);' >> /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
                ls -lah /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
                cat /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
                httpd -M | grep -e cgid -e alias
                chmod a+x /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/test.pl
                perl -le 'print for @INC'
                echo "Which perl : "
                which perl
                httpd-foreground
```

When I go to http://localhost:3000/cgi-bin/test.pl I see that `/somedir` is not in `@INC`. Hovewer `perl -le 'print for @INC'` contains `/somedir`.
WTF?

Comment: Do you have more than one Perl installation in place? Are you running under different user accounts? Environments don't get copied from one user to another under different circumstances. Test at the command line with both users and see if they have the same things in `@INC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating the problem I found by checking `httpd.conf` that httpd run `httpd-foreground` under `daemon` user, not root.

User `daemon` has no shebang by default:

```
$ docker run -it httpd cat /etc/passwd | grep daemon
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

But even if we add

```
runuser - daemon -c "export PERL5LIB=/somedir" -s /bin/bash
```

to `command:` it wouldn't pass a variable to perl since httpd run CGI scripts in separate, isolated processes so shell is isolated too. We can control ENV variables only by using [mod_env](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html) `SetEnv` and `PassEnv` directives.

So, for passing `/somedir` to `@INC` we need to add

```
echo "SetEnv PERL5LIB /somedir" >> /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```